# Why can I not assign a value to my ivar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, instance-variables

it has been a while since I did anything in ObjC. I am sure the mistake is trivial but I can't seem to find it.

I created a class called Game with the following .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FSGame : NSObject

@property NSInteger numberOfGames;

@end
```

In the implementation file of one of my view controllers, a method then uses the user's selection from a segm. control to determine the number of games:

```
FSGame *game;

// Number of Games
NSInteger index = _segCtrlNumberGames.selectedSegmentIndex;
if (index == 0) {
    game.numberOfGames = 1;
} else if (index == 1) {
    game.numberOfGames = 3;
} else {
    game.numberOfGames = 5;
}

NSLog(@"Games: %i; index: %i", game.numberOfGames, index);
```

The `NSLog` returns: `Games: 0; index: 2`

I have the same issue with two other classes I created. I grab text from a `UITextField` and the NSLog displays it correctly so I know I am actually able to get the user's input - it just wont store it as an ivar.

This must be something really obvious. Any pointers?

Comment: Allocate the game object

Comment: If you don't allocate the game object it won't store in memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create the Game object:

```
Game *game;
```

But you should create NSGame instead and you need to allocate and initialise it as well:

```
FSGame *game = [[FSGame alloc] init];
```

Comment: Argh, I *knew* it was something stupid like that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, unlike other languages, uninitialized objects in Objective-C do not contain garbage value, they are initialized as nil. And you can send messages to nil objects without crashing your application.

Comment: @ArslanAli Only when using ARC... With MRC, pointers to objects are not initialised to nil...